# LDAP User Information

Tags: python-3.x, ldap, ldap-query, python-ldap

When a employee leaves a company, is his ldap account disabled or removed. I mean is his information like his previous e-mail, company Id still retrievable through ldap search or is it completely removed from the Active directory.

Comment: This is obviously a choice by the Organization. If it is removed it is removed. (After a short while)

Comment: @jwilleke how do they store previous employee data

Comment: That depends on your company's policy. Ask your network administrator.

Comment: Historical employee information is usually in an HR application. But ask the organization.